# resize numpy array referencing another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

```
mypath='/Users/sachal/Desktop/data_raw/normal_1/images'
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
images = np.asarray(np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object))

for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
  images[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) )
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
resized = np.asarray(np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object))
img_f = np.asarray(np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object))


for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
  resized[n] = cv2.resize(images[n],(101,101))
  img_f[n] = cv2.cvtColor(resized[n], cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

train_img =  np.asarray(img_f)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above code first I am loading images using opencv then I am resizing and changing their colour space in the second block.

My batch size is `6408` and dimensions of images are `101*101*3`
When i do `train_img.shape` i get`(6408,)` and upon `train_img[i].shape` i get `101*101*3` and I am unable to train my neural network model because of this and the dimensions i want are `6408*101*101*3`

I tried reshaping with this `train_img.resize(6408,101,101,3)` i got this `ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function`

and while fitting my model with i got this error `Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (6408, 1)`

I want to know if i can change the dimensions of my input with the current method i am using to load my images.

Comment: Please try to provide a working example without local links to your data. Embedd a small matrix with values to show what you mean.

Comment: what I want is `[1 1 1 1]` this type of matrix but what i am getting is first a list of 6408 elements then each element is [1 1 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `dtype=object` here. OpenCV creates `ndarray` images anyway.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```py
mypath='/Users/sachal/Desktop/data_raw/normal_1/images'
onlyfiles = [ f for f in os.listdir(mypath) if os.path.isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
images = []

for file in onlyfiles:
   img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath,file))
   resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (101, 101)) 
   yuv_img = cv2.cvtColor(resized_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
   images.append(yuv_img.reshape(1, 101, 101, 3))

train_img = np.concatenate(images, axis=0)
print(train_img.shape)
```

In the loop, you load each image, resize it, convert it to YUV then put it in a list. At the end of the loop, your list contains all your training images. You can pass it to `np.concatenate` to create an `ndarray`.